# Stop wpf Storyboard and hold actual value

Tags: c#, wpf

I have following wpf code

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Image x:Key="MyImage" Source="../Assets/icon.ico"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <Storyboard x:Key="AkomiLogoAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Image.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                            By="360"
                            SpeedRatio="0.5"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                            FillBehavior="Stop"
                            />
        </Storyboard>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtAuto"/>

                <Image Source="../Assets/icon.ico" Width="20" Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                <Image.Resources>
                    <converter:IsNullConverter x:Key="IsNullConverter"/>
                </Image.Resources>
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0" />
            </Image.RenderTransform>
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtAuto, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="AkomiRotation" Storyboard="{StaticResource AkomiLogoAnimation}">
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  ElementName=txtAuto, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource IsNullConverter}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AkomiRotation" >
                                </StopStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
```

The goal is to rotate the image as soon as some text has been entered. But stopping the storyboard lets the image angle jump into it's initial value.

I tried to add `FillBehavior="HoldEnd"` to the Storyboard definition, but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Maybe I can access the angle-value at the end of the animation anyhow and set this value in `RotateTransform`

Comment: arent you rotating 360 (meaning all the way back to where it started)?????

Comment: @TYY yes, it will constantly rotate in same direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried PauseStoryboard, instead of stop? Also, you should change fillbehavior on the animation

Comment: I would like to add that if using `PauseStoryboard` (which may be the only choice), we don't need to care about the `FillBehavior`, `FillBehavior` is meaningful only when the Storyboard is actually ended.

Comment: But what if the animation pauses , lets say after 60°, and then you want to rotate it not the remaining 300, but full 360° again?

Comment: The Storyboard should be repeated forever of course. Without being repeated, sooner or later it will be stopped and then `PauseStoryboard` has no effect.

Comment: Oh, I missed that RepeatBehavior. Now it makes sense

Comment: where is PauseStoryboard in code? if I do `sb.Pause()` the animated properties are still frozen